# Looking at similar features in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Ultimate Edition) from Eclipse / “Clean”, “File Browser” and “Server Instance” for JBoss

Tags: intellij-idea

I migrated from Eclipse IDE to IntelliJ recently and I missed some features that I consider important, which I may not be found, follow them (see image):

Versions Used:

- Eclipse IDE Mar Release 4.5.0
- IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.2
- JBoss EAP 5.1

1º (Feature A in the image) - When working with Jboss in Eclipse I have the option to use “clean” that cleans the data from the last deploy. This leaves the internal structure clean as if you had just downloaded Jboss and used it the first time. How do I do this “clean” in IntelliJ? Is there a button for this or do I need to put some instructions in the “VM options” in IntelliJ or somewhere else, when starting JBoss?

2º (Feature B in the image) When working with Jboss in Eclipse sometimes I need to open the folder where the deployment is happening on my machine, this feature in Eclipse called "File Browser" that is inside "Show in". Where do I find something equivalent in IntelliJ?

3º (Feature C in the image) When working with Jboss on IntelliJ, the “Server Instance” feature exists only for the “Local” option, for “Remote” it does not exist. How to work with these two resources, "Server Instance" and "Remote", at the same time in IntelliJ?

Image: [IntelliJ  and Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZifQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [Undeploy action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/deployment-console.html).
2. For the file/folder in the project view there is a menu item to open it in our OS file manager, for example Show in Explorer. Deployment is performed into the [artifact output directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) which you should be able to browse to in the Project View when the option to hide output directories is not enabled.
3. Since the server is started remotely, IDE has no control over instance and this option is not available. If you need this feature, please [submit a request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the use case and more details.

Comment: thank you for your answers.
1. Ok
2. As I understand it using IntelliJ, the path to get to the artifact inside the JBoss deployment folder may be longer, compared to Eclipse IDE which has only one button. Anyway, is there an explanatory video showing this feature on IntelliJ?
3. In Eclipse IDE there is no such distinction, remote or otherwise, to use this feature. Soon I will need the same feature on Intellij. I will open a request to create this resource for the remote as well.

Comment: See https://i.imgur.com/iYChJlr.png for the artifact output path. Here is how you can open it from the project in the file manager: https://i.imgur.com/JWANdM0.png.